# How to add flink metrics in scope other than operator-scope (jm, job, tm, ...)

Tags: apache-flink, prometheus, metrics

I am trying to add my custom metrics (a simple gauge) that is scoped to JM or Job.

However, in the [docs](https://hdfs://dev02/user/flink_statestore/savepoint/tonegawa-dev/load-test-bucket-1/savepoint-000000-09480a06c61d), it only shows how to add metrics by accessing context from `RichFunction`, which in most (if not all) cases are operator scoped. I do not want my metrics duplicated for each operator. I tried digging down the source code but to no avail.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Flink's metric system isn't designed to support that. If you want metrics for your user functions that are aggregated across multiple instances or multiple operators, at least some metrics systems (e.g., prometheus, influxdb) can do that for you.

Comment: My purpose is actually to add metadata via prom label, so that it can directly be used in grafana as variables. Adding the metadata operator-wise will makes a lot unnecessary duplicate. Also adding another custom exporter would be too much for such simple addition. I am wondering if you have any suggestion for it.

Comment: I can’t think of any way to do that.